# Remove web_external_layout from existing odoo report

Tags: odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13

I want to remove the external headers and footers from the payslip report.

The problem I have is that there are no hooks I know off to attach into xpath before the  div with class `page` in any report.

This is the line I want to take out. For simplicity I have just attached the code where the problem is.

Thank you in advance.

```
<template id="report_payslip">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="web.external_layout"> =>this line
                <div class="page">
                    <h2>Pay Slip</h2>
                    <p t-field="o.name"/>
```

Or is there a way I can replace the report that calls this layout, without necessarily getting rid of it? A way to make it call my custom report.

```
<report 
   id="action_report_payslip" 
   model="hr.payslip" 
   string="Payslip"
   report_type="qweb-pdf"
   name="hr_payroll.report_payslip" 
   file="hr_payroll.report_payslip"
   print_report_name="'Payslip - %s' % (object.employee_id.name)"
   />
```

Comment: You could change the `t-call` value to either an empty template or another layout template.

Comment: Is that via extension or directly changing the original file?

Comment: Just create a new external layout template and via payslip template extension (change) just replace the `t-call` value with your new external layout template.

Answer (score 0):

To remove or modify the content of the template, you need to inherit it.
Example:

```xml
<odoo>
    <template id="external_layout_inherited" inherit_id="web.external_layout">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('header')]" position="replace">
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

In the above code, it replaces the header of the external template.

you can see [dev doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/reports.html#barcodes) for more info.

Comment: This extension will affect all other reports, while I just want to change the payslips report.

Comment: then just add [t-if](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/qweb.html#conditionals) to exclude it.